# Can't connect to a nginx server deploy in a EC2 instance

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm running a nginx in a EC2 instance.
When trying to connect it with public dns, I get "connection timed out" error.
I run `curl 127.0.0.1`, it print nginx home page, so the nginx configure is fine.
I thins there is something wrong with my EC2 instance's security policy,but I have already set it to allow all the traffic in and out.[image: the security setting:]

Thank u,guys.

Comment: IF you got the answer. Provide an answer in "Your Answer" text area. And choose it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the iptable block the 80 port.
Flush iptables,it works.